# Java Interactive Gantt Chart Drawing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to draw an interactive "Gantt-Chart" in Java for a project at school. I'm not really used to working with Java-GUI, thats why I would need some Input from your side :)

What I'm trying to get (Example for 1 resource only)

```
Resource | Period 1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P5 | P6 | ...
R1       |=====|    |=======|==========|
R1       |==========|       |====|
```

`|=======|` shall be a production scheduled on that specific resource

==> If there is more than 1 production per period, i don't want them to overlap, but place them beneath each other.

**What I got already/thought about:**

- I can use JLabels for the Productions
- I can put them on a Grid
- I need the JLabels to be interactive --> MouseEventListeners that realize the position the JLabels have been dragged

**What I have no idea about:**

- How to start...?

  - Taking a JPanel and put some kind of a 2DGrid on it...
  - Then place the Labels on it...
  - Then check if they overlap <-- I got no clue how to check that one except checking pixel for pixel?
  - Then place the JPanel below the one, they overlapped
- Is it possible to take some kind of GridbagLayout or sth like that to place the JPanels inside of the Grid? So they take care of not overlapping by themselves?

I know that my questions are very.... unspecific... But maybe someone could give me some ideas about how to start, what classes I have to look into first to really realize how to do something like that...

Answer (score 2):

If the Gantt chart is not your project but just a display you need then you can use a library like [JFreeChart](http://jfree.org/jfreechart/) to make the plot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... Is it possible to edit a JFreeChart Diagram the way I want it? Cuz I can't change the layout... And can I make it interactive with JFree?

Comment: Yes, using the API you can generate it as you like, even with tooltips or other annotations, and it is interactive. Just look at their demo (web start) application, there are several examples of Gantt, and you can also see how interactive the plots can be.

Comment: Hmm sounds like I could use this... But still i would prefer to "paint" all the Elements by my own since it's for a project at school and JFreeChart shouldn't be the answer to that :S